# Update multiple paths in a single invocation

Tags: json, bash, jq

Is there a way to use jq in Bash to update multiple values in a json file at once? For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

explore_host_name () {
  host_name_lastrun=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N')
  host_name_value="$(hostname)"
  result=$(jq --arg host_name_value "$host_name_value" '.host.properties.name.value = $host_name_value' data/firemotd-data-host.json)
  echo "${result}" > data/firemotd-data-host.json
  result=$(jq --arg host_name_lastrun "$host_name_lastrun" '.host.properties.name.lastrun = $host_name_lastrun' data/firemotd-data-host.json)
  echo "${result}" > data/firemotd-data-host.json
}

explore_host_name
```

The json file:

```
{
  "host": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "generated": "@logon",
        "value": "${host.name}",
        "lastrun": "2020-06-09 20:48:00,357",
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to update `host.properties.name.lastrun` and `host.properties.name.value` at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
jq --arg hpnl foo --arg hpnv bar '.host.properties.name.lastrun = $hpnl | .host.properties.name.value = $hpnv' file
```

Output:

```
{
  "host": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "generated": "@logon",
        "value": "bar",
        "lastrun": "foo",
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In JQ you can pipe the result of an assignment to another. E.g:

```
jq --arg host_name_value   "$host_name_value"   \
   --arg host_name_lastrun "$host_name_lastrun" '
.host.properties.name |= (
  .value   = $host_name_value   |
  .lastrun = $host_name_lastrun
)' data/firemotd-data-host.json
```